# How to compile newley added source file in visual studio 2012?

Tags: visual-c++

I'm trying to compile the newly added source file for Windows32 project in visual express 2012 but all time the visual studio in compiling the previously existing file i.e the file which is provided by studio. Please Help.

Comment: Did you try to refresh the project after adding the file?

Answer (score 0):

1.Delete the old file.

2.Add new file.

3.Clean the solution.

4.Build the solution